# How to disable ad-hoc wireless connections?

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I have Intel 5100 AGN on my laptop. I want to make sure it wont make ad-hoc wireless connection ever.

Couldnt find anything suitable in Advanced adapter settings (was looking for something like Infrastructure Only)..

The OS is Windows 7 x64

Comment: Your wireless connection manger should tell you if it is a connection to a router or another (ad hock) PC. So it is really up to you what wireless connection you choose to connect to. I don't know of a way to disable all ad hock connections on Windows 7, maybe someone else knows, great question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how to disable ad hoc networks on Vista, It should work on W7 as well

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsVista/AdminTips/Security/HowtoDisableAdHocWirelessConnectionsonVista.html

> Windows Vista won’t automatically create ad hoc wireless connections with other computers, but for greater security you may want to disable ad-hoc wireless connections entirely. You can do this by running the following Netsh command at an elevated command prompt:
>
> netsh wlan add filter permission=denyall networktype=adhoc
>
> To re-enable ad hoc wireless connections, run this command:
>
> netsh wlan del filter permission=denyall networktype=adhoc

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `Network and Sharing Center` then select from the left hand "Manage Wireless Networks", you should see every wireless network your computer is set to automatically connect to.

If there are no Ad-Hoc Networks listed, your machine will not connect to one automatically.

As long as you do not create or join an Ad-Hoc network, your machine will never automatically connect to one (Unless someone Spoofs one with the same name as a network you use etc, but that is always the risk of using wireless - and it is highly unlikely).

There is a more complicated way of actually disabling it - If you have access to group policy editor and the Wireless templates, you can set it to only connect to "Access 
point (infrastructure) network only." If you want a full guide for this, let me know and I will write one.

Comment: ... Sorry about the above, not trying to be lazy but I do not have access to a machine with group policy editor at the moment so I wouldn't be able to make a good accurate guide or screenshots. If you need it, I will make one when I have access to another machine.

Comment: thats ok. i used netsh as per moab post

Comment: No problem - Looks like a better answer! I learn something new as well!